# Insufficient definition of replicate

Tags: haskell

I have a question that I think is rather tricky.

> The standard prelude contains the function
>
> ```
> replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
> ```
>
> The following might seem like a reasonable definition for it
>
> ```
> replicate n x = take n [x,x,..]
> ```
>
> But it is actually not sufficient. Why not?

I know that the `replicate` function is defined as:

```
replicate        :: Int -> a -> [a]       
replicate n x    =  take n (repeat x)
```

And `repeat` is defined as:

```
repeat           :: a -> [a]  
repeat x         =  xs where xs = x:xs
```

Is the definition insufficient (from the question) because it uses an infinite list?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the suggested definition? The compiler might tell you why there's something wrong with that. (And by the way, you should copy the text in your question, and avoid images.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all there is a small syntax error in the question, it should be:

```
replicate n x = take n [x,x..]
--                         ^ no comma
```

but let's not be picky.

Now when you use range syntax (i.e. `x..`), then `x` should be of a type that is an instance of `Enum`. Indeed:

```
Prelude> :t \n x -> take n [x,x..]
\n x -> take n [x,x..] :: Enum a => Int -> a -> [a]
```

You can argue that `x,x..` will only generate `x`, but the Haskell compiler does not know that at compile time.

So the type in `replicate` (in the question) is **too specific**: it implies a type constraint - `Enum a` - that is actually *not* necessary.

Your own definition on the other hand is perfectly fine. Haskell has no problem with infinite lists since it uses lazy evaluation. Furthermore because you define `xs` with `xs` as tail, you actually constructed a circular linked list which also is better in terms of memory usage.

Comment: The circular linked list used to define `repeat` doesn't make this definition of `replicate` any better than one written in a more straightforward recursive fashion. `replicate` inherently needs to allocate the full length of the list (lazily). What actually happens in GHC is that the `repeat` used here will fuse (via rewrite rules) with the `take`, producing something much like a hand-written `replicate`.

Comment: @dfeuer: it indeed does not improve the definition of `replicate`, but my point is that it can for some cases improve the definition of others that depend on `repeat` (and thus improves `repeat` itself). For instance a hypothetical `sumLess` that is a test that succeeds if the sum is less. Since you keep working on the same reference, the memory usage will not increase if `sumLess` is walking through the `repeat`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the explanation.